# How do I move or copy a single path?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, path

I know this is a ridiculously basic question, but I cannot seem to do it for the life of me, even though I did it just 5 minutes ago...

I'm trying to copy the path on the right over to the left side of the heart. Even though only the right "lung" section is selected with the move tool (and Auto-select "Layer"), both this and the heart move when I attempt to move anything. If I turn Auto-select layer off, then the heart shape moves, even though this shape is selected! Why does this happen if they're on separate layers?

More pressingly, whenever I copy this path (on to a new layer or not) and either move or transform it, the first version of it moves/transforms at the same time. Very frustrating indeed! I cannot seem to separate the copy in order to make separate adjustments...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The heart and the "right lung" layers are linked together. This is indicated by the little chain icon on the right of the layers. Select both of them, right click, and select `Unlink Layers`

[image: Unlink Layers]